# How to make API internal calls in Next.JS 13 without the base URL?

Tags: next.js, fetch, next.js13

I've been playing with the [Taxinomy](https://github.com/shadcn/taxonomy) project from Shadcn.

The fetch calls to the internal API don't include the app's base URL (http://localhost:3000 or the actual website for production).

```
// Get stipe checkout URL
const response = await fetch("/api/users/stripe")
```

I've been trying to replicate the behavior on my Next.JS 13.4 project but without any luck.

The `next.config` file doesn't include any particular config, the only mention to the APP URL is the `.env` with "NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL", but even when creating a `.env.local / .env / .env.development.local` and adding the `env` variable, it doesn't work.

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

[image: NextJS error: failed to parse URL from /api/users]

Any idea how I can call an API without needing a base URL?

Answer (score 0):

NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL is just an environment variable.
It is not a special value that implements specific behavior in NextJS.

When passing a URL to the fetch function, if you pass the PATH rather than the entire URL, the URL of the current web page is automatically added in front.

However, this cannot be done in the server component because it does not run in the browser.

I also checked out the Taxinomy project.
The fetch function used in the Client Component passes path as an argument and
The fetch function used in Server Component passes the full URL as an argument.

It appears to have been used in the right way.

If you want to enter only the PATH rather than the full URL in the server component,
There is a way to port the fetch function again.

```
const http = (url, other) => return fetch(process.env.BASEURL+url, other)
```